# Why was my definition request migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

Why was https://english.stackexchange.com/q/524832 migrated from Law? An ordinary anglophone wouldn't know the legal meaning. [Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524832/what-does-extended-mean#comment1279180_524832) hints to it

> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524832/what-does-extended-mIn legal documents, and elsewhere, "extended" can mean (among other things) "expanded in force or reach" or "prolonged in time." Without additional context, I don't think it's possible to discern which of these meanings (if either) the authors of the Treaty of Lisbon Protocol intended in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no particular, unique, or special legal meaning to the word.

Where it is used in legal documents (as in that particular question) it has the same meaning as if it were used in any other context.